# How to add WordPress jQuery library to frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using below method inside WordPress admin to use jQuery library and this is working fine and I don't need to add source for jQuery library for this method.

```
 <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // works inside WordPress admin without source
        }); 
  </script>
```

But the same method does not work on front end WordPress form and to make it work I've to add source of library?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          // need to add jQuery source 
        }); 
  </script>
```

Why do I need to add source of jQuery library for frontend? How can load WordPress JQuery library to frontend?

Answer (score 2):

It works in the admin, because there are admin scripts that have jQuery as a dependency and WordPress includes jQuery in order for those scripts to work.

You should use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function when adding scripts (not including them in scripts tags). Notice the `$deps` variable of the function, if you set that to `array( 'jquery' )`, WordPress will include the library for you, so your script can use it.

[If you scroll down the page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) you can see which libraries are included in WordPress and what handles are used to enqueue them.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to ensure that jQuery is enqueued. it should be but just to ensure it is add the following in the header.php

```
<?php
function my_jq_queue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jq_queue' );
?>
```

after that you can add your script as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // add add your function in the format $()

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've to add this in plugin. Where do i need to add it to plugin? Is to add in main plugin file?

Comment: the php function should run as a separate function in the main plugin file. you can add the javascript inline or also enqueue it with a link to the javascript file see the link [http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-22509](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-22509)

Comment: please check my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983563/add-wordpress-jquery-to-cutom-page-template