# Add WordPress jQuery to cutom page template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a plugin and it has a below custom page template. This template requires jQuery. I've a variable $link_to_js liked to google library but I want it to link it to the WordPress internal jQuery library?

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: Checkout Template
*/


// Need to replace below with WordPress library???
//$link_to_js = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link href="<?php echo $link_to_css; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $link_to_js; ?>"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="authnet_container"><!--CONTAINER START-->

</div><!--FOOTER END-->

</body>
</html>
```

I've added below code in main plugin file but it does not add?

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Please advice the best way to add jQuery library to the custom plugin page template? Thanks

Comment: Wordpress comes up with jQuery library by default.So why do you want to enqueue it again ?

Comment: It does not enqueue jQuery in my case when i use my custom page template, I don't see jQuery in resources for custom page template. And yes it includes for default page template.

Comment: It does includes .. Try adding `get_header();` and `get_footer();`.

Comment: I've above custom page template. how can add get_header() inside it? It will disturb the layout of the page?

Comment: Yes it will because there will be two html tag and I really dont know your need to make it in that way ..

Comment: Is there any way to get the link to WordPress JQuery library?

Comment: It generally resides on `wp-includes > js > jquery.js`

Comment: Do you think this will be a good idea?

Comment: I never recommend that way :)

Answer (score 0):

You should include `<?php wp_head(); ?>` and `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` immediately before `</head>` and `</body>` respectively.

These functions are what, among other things, include scripts and styles that have been queued.

References:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer

At the very least add `<?php do_action("wp_enqueue_scripts"); ?>` as that will output all the queued scripts.

Comment: I can not use this. I have custom page template with custom header and footer. Please check my template above.

Comment: I've added another option to my answer. Also note that ```wp_head``` is not the same as ```get_header```.

Comment: I added <?php do_action("wp_enqueue_scripts"); ?> to the very bottom before </body> but still doesn't work?

Comment: Hey Irfan, Nick told you NOT to use do_action("wp_enqueue_scripts")